# Why do I get null lines after Collections.shuffle(List)?

Tags: java, collections, nullpointerexception, shuffle

I am writing some Java code to read each line of a data file into an array list, shuffle that list, and then perform some further operations on the shuffled data.  The problem is that, after shuffling, I am getting null elements for some of the elements in the array list.

```
//this file contains the data
String input = ...;
//this file contains the number of rows in the data file
String input2 = ...;
FileInputStream fstream2 = new FileInputStream(input2);
DataInputStream in2 = new DataInputStream(fstream2);
BufferedReader brIndex = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in2));

for(int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(input+(i+1)+".txt");
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader brData = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        num = Integer.parseInt(brIndex.readLine());

        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
            temp.add(brData.readLine());
        }
        brData.close();
        Collections.shuffle(temp);

        //read in shuffled data
        for(int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
            rowData = temp.get(j); ...
}
```

In executing the code, I get a `NullPointerException` after this when working with `rowData`.  The original file has 17,169 rows (none of them are null).  `temp.size()` is also 17,169 but when I printed temp out to the console, `temp.get(j)` was null for some `j` and not for others.

Can anyone explain to me why this is the case and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might be there are not enough lines in the file as `num`.

Try:

```
List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    temp.add(brData.readLine());
}
```

You could also check for null elements in the list before you actually shuffle the list, as shuffle does not insert any new element to the list.

Comment: Interesting ... I can open the file and see that there are 17,169 rows of data.  Yet, when I do as you suggested, it only reads in 13,000 rows (although it should be temp.add(line)).  That explains why I was getting 4,169 null elements scattered about after shuffling.  What I don't understand is ... what happened to the other 4,169 rows?

Comment: Oh ... sorry, I just found my mistake.  I was reading from the wrong file.  :) The file I read from did have 13000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

You never check if `readLine()` returns null or not. Check it, and you'll discover that you probably read past the end of the file.

Also, readers, writers and streams should always be closed in a finally block.

Comment: I admit, I am not careful about exception handling with try,catch and finally.  I should take more care to do that as you have suggested.  It's just that, currently, I am not part of any workflow.  All of this code and all of the data files are created / viewed only by me. So, I guess I am being a bit lazy.